# Autostart a GUI application as user after this user is logged in (automatically)

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, systemd, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I cannot figure out how to autostart a GUI application as the logged in user on the current Raspberry OS Full (Bookworm, 64-bit). I tried via `systemd`, but for some reason it fails, the error is as if the desktop environment is not fully initialized yet.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Autorun Service
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/start_my_app.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/
Restart=always
RestartSec=2s
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

What are other possible way? Any better ways? Or is there anything wrong with my .service file?

Comment: `for some reason` what reason, `the error is` what exactly? not your interpretation, what is the error?

Comment: Trying to start ANY program which interacts with users at boot is an exercise in futility (as any of the hundreds of similar questions indicate).

Comment: @Milliways: I am under impression that `graphical-session.target` should work, according to all descriptions, it's made just for this. And yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately you are mistaken. Whatever is in the service won't start until the target is satisfied BUT root can't do any I/O to the user. This can only happen AFTER login. There are autostart tools to do this but Bookworm uses new tools.

Comment: @Milliways: You can see in the .service file that I'm running as the user `pi`, not as root. And it still isn't supposed to work? 
Could you please point me to the appropriate tool(s) on Bookworm?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-in-kiosk-mode/ Scroll down to the first occurance of the word "wayfire" and start reading a paragraph before that, it should be very simple.  If that works out, please consider leaving an answer of your own, most of the ones here are out-of-date.   BTW, adding "User=pi" does not automatically mean the service is part of that user's login; for that you must invoke `systemctl --user enable` as user Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks: That works, thanks a lot! You should rightly post the answer. The official tutorial is slightly wrong, btw, in that there is no `[autostart]` section by default, but I added it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian 12.4 Bookworm on RPi4 only the "Traditional" methods of this link [How to Use Autostart for Desktop](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=294014) worked for me.

I created a .desktop file and it executed in both  /etc/xdg/autostart, and alternately, a created /home/pi/.config/autostart/ directories.

Comment: I did it as suggested in the comments - via `.config/wayfire.ini`, this also works as expected.